# Microarray Data: Finding Probes that have NO missing observations

Tags: r

Quite often, you'll download data and you want to know the difference in expression levels. Things get complicated as you can have more than one probe per sample.

In the following example, we have only two samples (i.e. 1 and 4):

Your `data` file will look something like this

```
  ProbeID      SampleID ExperimID    Value    Type
1 2747406        1         2      6.449200 AFFEXON
2 2747407        4         2      6.455550 AFFEXON
3 2747408        1         2      6.534564 AFFEXON
4 2747408        4         2      6.453523 AFFEXON
..etc
```

To see the issue at hand, extract sample 1 and 4 and see whether the vector lengths match:

```
Sample1 <- data[ data$SampleID == 1, ]    #Extract from data where SampleID == 1
Sample4 <- data[ data$SampleID == 4, ]    #Extract from data where SampleID == 4
dim(Sample1)                              #Return length of row and col using dim()
[1] 1012703  5 
dim(Sample4)
[1] 1411399  5
```

As seen above, the number of probes is unequal between the samples. This will create unequal  vector lengths for downstream analysis, making it difficult to COMPARE expression levels between the TWO samples. Thus, you need to find the probes with NO missing observations (i.e. we want probes that have 2 hits or frequency of 2, since we have 2 samples, and ignore the 1 hit probes. This will produce equal vector lengths and allow us to COMPARE expression levels between the TWO samples.

Here is one way of doing it:

```
probeTbl <- table(data[,1])               #Export probes into a table
head(probTbl)                             #Notice freq! We don't want the 1 hit ones.
2315101 2315102 2315103 ... 
  2       1       1
probeToSample <- which(probeTbl == 2)     #Export only those with 2 observations
head(probeToSample)                       #Check that probes -> to new variable
2315101 2315102 2315103 ...
  1       2       3               
numericPtoS <- as.numeric                 #Extract probeToSample as numeric vector 
(names(probeToSample))

WorkingData <- data[,1] %in% numericPtoS  #Use %in% logic operator to match original         
                                           #data with new vector numericPtoS, which 
                                           #contains desired hits or observations == 2
```

If anyone has a better way, please chip in. . .

Comment: Not trying to be pedantic, but trying to make sure I understand the data... are those first numbers row IDs? In which case, they should be `1` and `2`, correct? Or are those a part of the Probe ID?

Comment: As an aside, I'd like to eventually grow my `probemapper` package to help deal with microarray data such as this. If you have a handful of such functions which you'd find useful in a package meant to help deal with microarray expression data, I'd be happy to hear them! (`install.packages("probemapper"); maintainer("probemapper");`)

Comment: Jeff, thanks for catching that! I will most def check out the "probemapper" package.

Answer (score 1):

Not a novel answer, but maybe a more complete example and a couple of minor improvements to be a bit more universal.

My example includes 2 probes -- one which is present in 3 samples, one which is present in 2. I dynamically check for the number of samples (rather than your hardcoded `x==2`.

Can you confirm that this is the behavior you're looking for? If so, maybe we can make further improvements from here.

```
data <- read.table(text="ProbeID      SampleID ExperimID    Value    Type
 1 2747406        1         2      6.449200 AFFEXON
 2 2747407        1         2      6.455550 AFFEXON
 3 2747406        4         2      6.349200 AFFEXON
 4 2747407        4         2      6.755550 AFFEXON
 5 2747406        5         2      6.755550 AFFEXON")

freq <- table(data[,1])      #Export the probes into a table (with frequencies) 
compProbes <- freq[freq==max(freq)]  #Create new variable that contains probes with NO missing obs by identifying the probe with the maximum number of occurrences
compProbes <- as.numeric(names(compProbes)) #Extract name as numeric vector 
compRows <- data[,1] %in% compProbes    #Use %in% logic operator to match z and with probes=TRUE
newdata <- data[compRows,]
```